# Why is net favorability for Israel so high in Nigeria even after the Gaza incursions?

Tags: israel, nigeria

[image: Israel net favorability world map, showing Nigeria as the sole investigated country in Africa having a net favorable view of Israel in December 2023]

> *Source: Morning Consult Political Intelligence.*

[Image source](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/GEIk1IvX0AE-OQt?format=jpg&name=4096x4096)

Why is net favorability for Israel so high in Nigeria even after the Gaza incursions? I was reading an article on how Israel's net favorability went down drastically around the world, but I noticed that Nigeria's net favorability for Israel maintained a high level still even after the Gaza incursions. Is there a political, cultural, historical reason for this high level of favorability among the populace in Nigeria?

Comment: The source is in the image, but the guy who quoted the image is "my source".

Comment: The anwer(s) may be a bit obvious, but I see no prima facie reason to DV this into negative territory, so +1. Personally, I'd be curious how the other countries facing Islamist insurgencies in the same region view Israel. But we can see from your map Africa only has a few countries polled (at least by Morning Consult).

Comment: Somewhat interesting, but not so obvious/well-known story https://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-58917825 ibid, even longer take:  https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/apr/26/lost-jews-of-nigeria-igbo-judaism-israel

Comment: The image seems to be originally from a [paywalled report at morningconsult.com](https://pro.morningconsult.com/analyst-reports/year-ahead-in-geopolitical-risk-2024).  On X, [this post by Anatoly Karlin includes the image](https://twitter.com/powerfultakes/status/1748001069236400464), which might be where the OP got it from. For what it's worth, [Anatoly Karlin self-identifies as racist](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Anatoly_Karlin).  None of that is particularly relevant for Nigeria-Israel relations.

Comment: This question conflates general support for a country with support for some of its specific policies. These polices are not new and not unique to Israel. Friends often disagree. Nigeria has called for de-escalation and prioritization of civilian safety during the conflict.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nigeria and Israel have a [surprisingly strong relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Nigeria_relations)

> Since April 1993, Israel has maintained an embassy in Abuja and Nigeria has an embassy in Tel Aviv. Over fifty Israeli companies operate in Nigeria in the spheres of construction, infrastructure, hi-tech, communications and IT, agriculture and water management. In turn, there are over 5,000 Nigerian companies and organizations that operate in Israel. Trade and commerce are promoted by the Israeli Export and International Cooperation Institute, the Nigerian-Israeli Chamber of Commerce (NICC) and the Israel-Africa Chamber of Commerce.

Nigeria is also where Boko Haram [kidnapped 276 girls in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chibok_schoolgirls_kidnapping). Israel has [been assisting Nigeria with that issue](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/israel-nigeria-relations)

> On September 2, 2019, the Nigerian government announced it would partner with Israel to address security challenges, particularly the Boko Haram insurgence, facing Nigeria.

Remember that Hamas kidnapped some 230 people on October 7. It's likely the parallels there are not lost on the Nigerian people.

Comment: And note that the Boko Haram conflict has been more deadly on both sides than the conflict between Israel and Hamas.  Gaza has a higher peak fatality **rate** but nowhere near the highest total.